# element flickering when it gets dragged

Tags: javascript, css

Hello guys i have following problem:

Whenever i drag an element it flickers and it looks very annoying. I couldnt find the root of the problem.

Here is my code snippet:

```
  moveElement(element, e) {
    let clientX = e.clientX;
    let clientY = e.clientY;
    let offsetX = e.offsetX;
    let offsetY = e.offsetY;
    let height = element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    let width = element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      element.style.setProperty("left", clientX - (width - offsetX) + "px");
      element.style.setProperty("top", clientY - (height - offsetY) + "px");
    });
  }
```

Here is he full code:

```js
class Dragger{
  constructor() {
    this.drags = [];
    this.drops = [];
    this.mover = null;
    this.collectDragAndDrop();
  }
  dragItem(element) {
    element.style.setProperty("position", "fixed");
    this.mover = this.moveElement.bind(null, element);
    element.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mover);
  }

  moveElement(element, e) {
    let clientX = e.clientX;
    let clientY = e.clientY;
    let offsetX = e.offsetX;
    let offsetY = e.offsetY;
    let height = element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    let width = element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      element.style.setProperty("left", clientX - (width - offsetX) + "px");
      element.style.setProperty("top", clientY - (height - offsetY) + "px");
    });
  }
  dropItem(element) {
    element.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.mover);
  }
  collectDragAndDrop() {
    document.querySelectorAll("[drag]").forEach(element => {
      let name = element.attributes.drag.nodeValue;
      let findDup = this.drags.some(el => el.name === name);
      if (findDup) throw Error("Duplicated drag attribute: " + name);
      this.drags.push({
        element,
        name
      });
      element.addEventListener("mousedown", this.dragItem.bind(this, element));
      element.addEventListener("mouseup", this.dropItem.bind(this, element));
    });
  }
}

new Dragger();
```

```css
  .box1 {
    background: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
  }
  .box2 {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box1" drag="test"></div>
<div class="box2" drag="test2"></div>
```

Can somebody tell me why this flickers so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your math is wonky. You're only accounting for the current mouse position instead of calculating the amount of movement that has occurred. The only reason your boxes are moving at all is because the function is waiting for the animation frame so there is some change in those coordinates while it waits.

You should also consider that if the mouseup occurs while the mouse is no longer over the element, the element won't get the event and thus will continue dragging when you mouse back over it. It's better to set a flag that keeps track of the mouse state.

```js
var isMouseDown = false;
addEventListener("mousedown", ()=>isMouseDown = true);
addEventListener("mouseup", ()=>isMouseDown = false);
document.querySelectorAll("[drag]").forEach(element=>{
  element.addEventListener("mousemove", e=>{
    if(!isMouseDown) return;
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      element.style.left = rect.x + e.movementX + "px";
      element.style.top = rect.y + e.movementY + "px";
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.box1 {
    background: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute
  }
  .box2 {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box1" drag="test"></div>
<div class="box2" drag="test2"></div>
```

Comment: thank you. i also see that the box is slightly moving faster then the mouse?

Comment: that's because of the slight delay caused by `requestAnimationFrame`, you can account for that by calculating the mouse offset of the draggable element on mousedown and using that position to determine the new position instead of using the movement properties of the mouse event.